# How would you close this file descriptor?

Tags: ruby

Let's say you have the following code:

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}"

#in_file = open(from_file)
#indata = in_file.read
indata = open(from_file).read # Combined in_file and indata.

puts "The input file is #{indata.length} bytes long."

puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exist?(to_file)}"
puts "Ready, hit RETURN to continue or CTRL-C to abort."
$stdin.gets

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

puts "Alright, all done."

out_file.close
#in_file.close
```

How would you close the file descriptor invoked by `indata`? You will need to close `File open`, but `indata` is really a `(File open).read`.

P.S. Since it's a script, it will be closed automatically upon exit. Let's assume that we're running a general, consistently running backend service. And we don't know whether garbage collector will kick in, so we will need to explicitly close it. What would you do?

Comment: Uncomment what you had originally?

Comment: I would like to combine `in_file` and `indata` into one line. I'm not sure how I'd be able to close the FD if I combined the two lines into one.

Comment: You wouldn’t, so don’t do that.

Comment: Ah, interesting. There's no way? That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if it were due to my lack of knowledge, hence my question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are just copying the file...**

you could just use [FileUtils#cp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp):

```
FileUtils.cp("from_file", "to_file")
```

or even shell-out to the operating system and do it with a system command.

Let's suppose you want to do something to the input file before writing it to the output file.

**If `from_file` is not large,...**

you could "gulp it" into a string using [IO.read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-read):

```
str = IO.read(from_file)
```

manipulate `str` as desired, to obtain `new_str`, then then blast it to the output file using [IO#write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-write):

```
IO.write("to_file", new_str)
```

Note that for the class [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html):

```
File < IO #=> true # File inherits IO's methods
```

which is why you often see this written `File.read(...)` and `File.write(...)`.

**If `from_file` is large, read a line, write a line...**

provided the changes to be made are done for each line separately.

```
f = File.open("to_file", "w") # or File.new("to_file", "w")
IO.foreach("from_file") do |line|
  # < modify line to produce new_line >
  f.puts new_line
end
f.close
```

`foreach` closes `"from_file"` when it's finished. If `f.close` is not present, Ruby will close `"to_file"` when the method containing the code goes out of scope. Still, it's a good idea to close it in case other work is done before the code goes out of scope.

Comment: This is great. Thank you, Cary.

Answer (score 1):

[Passing `File.open` a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html#method-c-open) is generally a nice way to go about things, so I’ll offer it up as an alternative even if it doesn’t seem to be quite what you asked.

```
indata = File.open(from_file) do |f|
    f.read
end
```